# scrollview auto scroll when `pushViewController`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

In a `ViewController`, there are three `tableView`s in a scrollView:

[image]

when the `segment[1]` tapped `scrollView` scroll to the second `tableView`, and the `segment[2]` tapped `scrollView` scroll to the third `tableView`

the problem is, if the second `tableView` is displayed now, when call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];`, the `scrollView` auto display the first `tableView`,but its contentOffset is still {320,height}

Comment: Is the `viewController` your are pushing a new and different `ViewController`?

Comment: @lucianomarisi new one, but both under the same `NavigationController`

Comment: So if its a new `ViewController`, how is the `scrollview` of the previous `ViewController` relevant?

Comment: @lucianomarisi When `popViewController` from new ViewController, I found the scrollView always display the first tableView.

Comment: When you come back to your first VC(with scrollView) by popping, you see the scrollView scrolled 1st tableView right? Also, can you provide some code you have tried?